# Mac Error Code -108

Tags: macos, mac, audio-recording

I began working on a project in Digital Performer 8.03 yesterday. When I went back to it today, the file would not open and produced the error message: "The application 'Digital Performer' can't be opened. -108". This error code is, apparently, a "server allocator error". All other Digital Performer files open fine. I am running OSX 10.8.3.

Is there a way to get the file to open?

Comment: On a whim, I decided to pull it off of the external drive that it was on -- it opened fine on both my machine's drive and a different external drive 

I'd still like to know what this is about, though. Maybe the hard drive in question is reaching the end of the road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to open your file. Close other programs that you don't need when you're going to access the file again. The error shows that you're computer's memory is not sufficient to open the file, so better to shut down other programs or background applications to get good allocation for your file.

Try to restart too.

Comment: Thanks, Kryte! Still, is it weird that the file opened everywhere but one specific drive?